# how to split the filename using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, python-2.7

I am using python to create xml file using element and subelement process.
I have a list of zip files in my folder listed below:

```
Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_getPlankeys_rev1_2021_03_09.zip
Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_secretmanager_rev1_2021_03_09.zip
Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_mypru_plankeys_rev1_2021_03_09.zip
Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_value_rev1_2021_03_09.zip
Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_v1_balances_rev1_2021_03_09.zip
```

I want to split those zip files and get the name  like this:

```
Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_getPlankeys
Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_secretmanager
Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_mypru_plankeys
Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_value
Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_v1_balances
```

PS: I want to remove `_rev1_2021_03_09.zip` while creating a name from the zip file.

here is my python code. It works with `Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_getPlankeys_rev1_2021_03_09.zip` but its not working if i have too big names for a zip file for eg `Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_v1_balances_rev1_2021_03_09.zip`

```
    Proxies = SubElement(proxy, 'Proxies')
    path = "./"
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if '.zip' in f:
            Proxy = SubElement(Proxies, 'Proxy')
            name = SubElement(Proxy, 'name')
            fileName = SubElement(Proxy, 'fileName')
            a = f.split('_')
            name.text = '_'.join(a[:3])
            fileName.text = str(f)
```

Comment: Is the bit you want to strip from the end always the same, i.e. `_rev1_2021_03_09.zip`? Or does it vary, but always follow that pattern, e.g. on another day it might be `_rev8_2021_03_11.zip`?

Comment: I think the problem lies with the second-last line: `name.text = '_'.join(a[:3])`. At the moment, it's just taking the first 3 segments from the `_` splits. Since your filenames have different lengths at the start, this is sometimes cutting off parts of the filename. Since the ending *is* consistent, you could change the `3` to `-4`, which will take everything up to the last four segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `str.split` by `rev1_`

```
>>> filenames

['Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_getPlankeys_rev1_2021_03_09.zip',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_secretmanager_rev1_2021_03_09.zip',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_mypru_plankeys_rev1_2021_03_09.zip',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_value_rev1_2021_03_09.zip',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_v1_balances_rev1_2021_03_09.zip']

>>> names = [fname.split('_rev1_')[0] for fname in filenames]

>>> names

['Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_getPlankeys',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_secretmanager',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_mypru_plankeys',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_value',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_v1_balances']
```

Same can be achieved with `str.rsplit` by limiting the `maxsplit` to `4`:

```
>>> names = [fname.rsplit('_', 4)[0] for fname in filenames]
>>> names
['Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_getPlankeys',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_secretmanager',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_v1_mypru_plankeys',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_value',
 'Retirement_participant-plan_info_resetcache_param_v1_balances']
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually worked. I have just updated my code with the logic you said: ```for f in os.listdir(path):
        if '.zip' in f:
            Proxy = SubElement(Proxies, 'Proxy')
            name = SubElement(Proxy, 'name')
            fileName = SubElement(Proxy, 'fileName')
            a = f.split('_rev1_')[0]
           # a = f.split('_')
            name.text = a
           # name.text = '_'.join(a[:5])
            fileName.text = str(f)```

Comment: can we define a variable using argparse on this logic ```names = [fname.split('_rev1_')[0] for fname in filenames]`` using ```names = [fname.split('_repa.version_')[0] for fname in filenames]``` it didnt work for me. Do you advise a better way!

Answer (score 0):

If the rev and date is always the same (`2021_03_09`), just replace them with the empty string:

```py
filenames = [f.replace("_rev1_2021_03_09.zip", "") for f in os.listdir(path)]
```